TIFF image file reconstruction from Hex Code
I've been working on a "small" side project for the past year or so on and off where it requires me to extract data from a old piece of software.
It has been really fun the highs are high and the lows are so frustrating but I'm finally near the end of the puzzle I believe, but little did I know this was going to be my gray hair moment in life.
The software has diagrams stored inside 1 huge file which from my research seem to be group 4 compressed TIFF image data surrounded by some other software specific image markers.
I've been experimenting with the hex code in order to get a image output with no luck and was wondering if anyone had some insight into this sort of thing, long shot I know...
https://pastebin.com/j06PUeMV
This is the header seperated from what I believe is the image data:
4D 4D 00 2A 00 00 00 08 00 09 01 00 00 30 00 00 01 02 F8 00 00 01 01 00 03 00 00 00 01 04 58 00 00 01 03 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 04 00 00 10 60 00 30 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 01 11 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 82 01 16 00 03 00 00 00 01 04 58 00 00 01 17 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 20 B2 01 1A 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 7A 01 1B 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 7A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 00 00 00 01

The link above is what I have gotten to so far which is a 130 byte TIFF header prepended to the image data that I've extracted from the bigger 1GB data file.
Can anyone see why this would not render a image as it is or guide me in the direction of useful resources?
I've extracted what I believe to be the image data from the original 1GB file and prepended a valid TIFF header expecting a image to be rendered but with no luck, I'm not sure if I'm missing other data or not.

I am not sure to understand your question. Is the file a complete TIFF, or are you prepending a TIFF header yourself? In the first case, did you try a TIFF dump utility?

It is a incomplete TIFF, it seems the software had a large IMAGEF.DAT file which has many TIFF files without the headers included.
I found a resource which explained the format of the file which seems to match here: https://priuschat.com/threads/toyota-electronic-parts-catalog-format-of-imagef-dat.208729/#post-2927041
Using this I extracted the image data and neccesary height, width and byte size parameters for the headers and then preappended them but with no avail.

The header you've shown (and have in the pastbin) doesn't match the description you linked to in the priuschat.  Specifically, there is some sort of offset; note the byte that is 0x30 -- this is where a valid tiff datatype should be, and should probably be 0x03.  Then there appears to be a dropped byte, at which point I'm guess the image width is  0x2f8 = 760; the next couple of tags then read correctly with a height of 0x458 = 1112 and a compression of T6, then we've dropped another nibble so the 0x106 tag is misaligned, and another nibble after that.
